# How to setup www to non-www redirect using advanced host and path rule?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to redirect all requests from `www.ray.run` to `ray.run`.

This is what I've tried:

```
defaultService: $[DEFAULT_SERVICE_URL]
name: matcher1
routeRules:
  - matchRules:
      - prefixMatch: /
    priority: 1
    urlRedirect:
      hostRedirect: ray.run
      pathRedirect: $[REDIRECT_PATH]
      redirectResponseCode: MOVED_PERMANENTLY_DEFAULT
      stripQuery: False
```

As far as I understand it, `$[DEFAULT_SERVICE_URL]` is a variable that I do not need to replace.

[image]

I would this to just work, but clicking Save just produces an Unknown error:

[image]

This is a screenshot of the load balancer itself:

[image]

What am I not doing right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define $[DEFAULT_SERVICE_URL] and $[DEFAULT_SERVICE_URL] with the actual values or variables that you want to use.

```
name: matcher1
routeRules:
  - matchRules:
      - hostMatch: www.ray.run
    priority: 1
    urlRedirect:
      hostRedirect: ray.run
      pathRedirect: $[REDIRECT_PATH]  # You need to define this variable
      redirectResponseCode: MOVED_PERMANENTLY_DEFAULT
      stripQuery: True  # Change to True if you want to strip query parameters
```

Comment: `$[REDIRECT_PATH]` but what if I want to retain the path that user navigated to?

Comment: For others reading this, you can omit `pathRedirect` property entirely.

Comment: You can derive the `defaultService` from `gcloud compute backend-services list --uri`. The final value should look something like: `projects/rayrun/global/backendServices/rayrun-blog`. The part that threw me is that I tried to piece together this value myself, and instead of `global`, I used whatever the region I am deployed to, which turns out to be wrong. You have to use `global`.